# How to add IPv6 loopback address as redirect uri in Azure for OAuth2?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm unable to add the IPv6 loopback address [::1] in Azure for use with OAuth2. I can add 127.0.0.1 just fine, but the field validation does not allow the IPv6 variant, and trying to authorize with OAuth2 using [::1] fails without it.

I tried both the page as seen in the image and the "new experience" version.

This seems like a massive oversight in the Azure Portal, unless I'm mistaken?

I've also tried 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 in colon-hexadecimal notation with the same error.

[image: Azure URI validation issue]

Comment: It seems to be a product limitation. We cannot give you a good answer here. You'd better to contact Microsoft Support directly by opening a support ticket. They may help you to confirm this issue by reaching Azure AD product group.

Comment: Yeah I also filed a bug with the Azure team. Hopefully they can sort it out:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34193

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately as of 7-1-2019, currently Azure Active Directory does not support IPV6 yet.

If you're interested in this feature please post it under the feedback section for Azure here : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback

And Microsoft's product group will look into it.

Comment: Thanks Frank I've added it to UserVoice, but if it's just a matter of allowing that redirect URI field to validate an IPv6 address as valid I would assume it to be trivial to implement no? :)

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/38058667-add-ipv6-support-in-azure-active-directory-so-it-l